# HOW TO FIX Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'nb-sidebar' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, sidebar, nebular

I'm new to Nebular, are there any other docs based on Nebular in detail?
I have already tried inserting a component in the module.
I made a sidebar component with a sidebar module.

App.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';<br>
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NbThemeModule, NbLayoutModule } from '@nebular/theme';
// import { SideBarComponent } from './side-bar/side-bar.component';
import { SideBarModule } from './side-bar/side-bar.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    // SideBarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NbThemeModule.forRoot({ name: 'cosmic' }),
    NbLayoutModule,
    SideBarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<nb-layout>

  <nb-layout-header fixed>
  <!-- Insert header here -->
  <a routerLink="/side-bar" routerLinkActive="active">SIDEBAR</a>

  </nb-layout-header>

  <nb-layout-column>

    <!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->


  </nb-layout-column>

  <nb-layout-footer fixed>
  <!-- Insert footer here -->
  </nb-layout-footer>

</nb-layout>
```

sidebar.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SideBarComponent } from './side-bar.component';
import { NbLayoutModule } from '@nebular/theme';
// import { SideBarService } from '../services/side-bar.service';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [SideBarComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NbLayoutModule,
  ]
})
export class SideBarModule { }
```

sidebar.comonent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { NbSidebarService } from '@nebular/theme';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-bar',
  templateUrl: './side-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-bar.component.scss']
})
export class SideBarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sidebarService:NbSidebarService){}
ngOnInit(){

}
toggle() {
  this.sidebarService.toggle(true);
  return false;
}

  }
```

sidebar.html

```
<nb-layout>

  <nb-layout-header subheader>
    <a href="#" (click)="toggle()"><i class="nb-menu"></i></a>
  </nb-layout-header>

  <nb-sidebar></nb-sidebar>

  <nb-layout-column>Layout Content</nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SideBarService {

  constructor() { }
}
```

I'm expecting to run the program as sidebar.
But how to fix this error?

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   'nb-sidebar' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'nb-sidebar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'nb-sidebar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
>     </nb-layout-header>
>
> [ERROR ->]<nb-sidebar></nb-sidebar>
>
> <nb-layout-column>Layout Content</nb-layout-column>
>   "): ng:///SideBarModule/SideBarComponent.html@6:2

Can anybody help?

Comment: Don't scream at us, please.

Comment: cant help it...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to import `NbSidebarModule` in your AppModule and SideBarModule

**app.module.ts**

```
import {NbSidebarModule} from '@nebular/theme'

@NgModule({
  //...
  imports: [
    //...
    SideBarModule,
    NbSidebarModule.forRoot() //<== add this
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**sidebar.module.ts**

```
import {NbSidebarModule} from '@nebular/theme'

@NgModule({
  //..
  imports: [
    NbSidebarModule //<== add this
  ]
})
export class SideBarModule { }
```

Comment: thanks this might help...!!!
how can i call <app-sidebar> instead of routers
its not happening..
it also gives same error
'app-side-bar' is not a known element:
how do you fix this

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. If your component is not recognised, you need to export it from your `SideBarModule` and import it in whichever module you are trying to use it. If this does not help, consider asking another question

Answer (score 0):

Try importing `SideBarModule` in your `sidebar.module.ts` instead of `App.module`

Comment: modules can not insert in its own module

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
// sidebar.module.
import { NbSidebarService } from '@nebular/theme';

// also import
  imports: [
    NbSidebarService 
  ]
})
```

Comment: service can not be in *imports* its in providers and i have already did that